# Result without a subquery

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to come up with a solution without a subquery which was asked in one of the interview.

`customerId` in Orders table is a foreign key referencing `id` in Customer table.

**Table: Customer:** `id` is a primary key
[image]
**Table Orders**
[image]

I was asked to calculate a percentage of each customer orders as compared to total units across the orders table. So, output should look like below:
**Output:**
[image]
**Below was my solution:**

```
select 
    c.name,
    COALESCE(SUM(o.units),0)/(select SUM(units) from orders)*100 as units
FROM customer c LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customerid
    group by c.id
```

Then interviewer asked to come up with a single query solution without using a subquery.

My answer was since we need a grouped sum based on customer id and then total sum of units, we will need two queries.

Does anyone know how this can be solved without using a subquery?

**Note:**
I see couple of comments saying it will error out/ query is not valid, however, it runs fine:
[image]

Comment: shouldn't your query have c.name as part of the GROUP BY? it would produce an error otherwise.

Comment: @tinazmu - why c.name? c.id is just fine because `id` is a primary key. You can have two customers with the same name but different `id`.

Comment: Maybe mysql can infer that but SqlServer gives an error (also you didn't say it was the primary key).

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Your code is not even valid.  It should result in error.

Comment: @Eric: why do you think it will result in error?

Comment: @tinazmu: I added a screenshot of successful run. Not sure why group by `c.id` would error and not `c.name`? Can you explain it? Join would run first then group by and then select. Group by `id` would roll up the `name` fine.

Comment: You now removed Sql Server tag! in SqlServer, you will get `Column 'customer.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`, because that is the rule. In your case MySql is helping you because it checks that c.name is dependent on c.id (SqlServer and many other RDBMSs do not).

Comment: I think what you are relying on is a SQL-99 feature (the feature is not yet adopted by major RDBMS vendors).

Comment: @tinazmu: I get your point behind grouping by `c.name`. However, do you think the question in the post can be solved by a single select query wihtout using any subquery?

Comment: Someone posted an answer using DISTINCT and `SUM(units) OVER(partition by c.Id)/SUM(units) OVER()`; I think that would work, but the GROUP BY method is the right way of doing it in my opinion.

Comment: @CodeBreaker Because it is not a valid syntax.  You must be using MySQL 5.7.  Even MySQL 8 won't run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using a *windowed* aggregate function to replace the subselect.

Typically, the overall total would be calculated with something like `SUM(o.units) OVER()`. However, since we are already within the scope of a group-by, we need to reference the group-by sum within the window function sum - `SUM(SUM(o.units)) OVER()`.

The `OVER()` qualifier without a `PARTITION BY` or `ORDER BY` sets the window scope to be the entire result set (the grand total).

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    SUM(o.units) As CustomerUnits,
    SUM(SUM(o.units)) OVER() AS TotalUnits,
    COALESCE(
        100.0 * SUM(o.units) / SUM(SUM(o.units)) OVER(),
        0
        ) As Percent
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customerid
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Results:

| id | name | CustomerUnits | TotalUnits | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Henry | 1 | 10 | 10.00000 |
| 2 | Sally | 0 | 10 | 0.00000 |
| 3 | Joe | 9 | 10 | 90.00000 |
| 4 | Max | null | 10 | 0.00000 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5STLZ8ZM) for a demo.

Comment: Yes, this works thanks. However, with window clause without groupby which tinazmu suggested in the comments above is much simpler:
SUM(units) OVER(partition by c.Id)/SUM(units) OVER() with DISTINCT keyword

Comment: In an interview evaluation, you might get "points off" for calculating the same result multiple times (once per order) and then using DISTINCT to discard the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    DISTINCT c.name,
  coalesce(SUM(o.units) OVER(PARTITION BY c.id),0)/SUM(o.units) OVER() * 100 as percent
FROM customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customerid
```

Comment: While this code my answer the question, your answer would benefit from having some explanation to what the code does to help future readers understand it